# Can't get proper encoding for JExcel/jxl

Tags: java, excel, jexcelapi

I have a problem of character encoding while using JExcel.
My app creates an excel document from a template and fills it with with data from a database (filled with current and previous sessions user-input) before sending it to the user.
In the final document, non-ASCII characters *FROM THE TEMPLATE* such as `é`, `è`, `à`, or `°` are not rendered properly (in the generated document, they appear properly in the template) and are instead replaced by `�` while those from the database are properly encoded.

I use UTF-8 for user input (and output to the viewing layer) as well as database storage.

I use this code in the class that generates the file:

```
    private void createFile(Arguments...)
            throws IOException, BiffException, RowsExceededException, WriteException
    {
            File XLSFile = new File(MyPath);
            WorkbookSettings XLSSettings = new WorkbookSettings()
            XLSSettings.setEncoding(Constants.TEMPLATE_ENCODING)
            // Constants.java is a class containing only app-wide constants declared as public static final
            Workbook template = Workbook.getWorkbook(
                    new File(Constants.TEMPLATE_PATH));
            WritableWorkbook userDocument =
                    Workbook.createWorkBook(XLSFile,template,XLSSettings);
            template.close();
            WritableSheet sheet = userDocument.getSheet(0);

            ...
                    Code that fills my workbook and sheet by creating new Labels and
                    adding them to my WritableSheet with sheet.add(Label)
            ...

            userDocument.write();
            userDocument.close();
    }
```

`Constants.TEMPLATE_ENCODING` has been set to `"Cp1252"` as was suggested in this question: [Encoding problem in JExcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701743/encoding-problem-in-jexcel) but to no avail however.

Trying to change it to `"UTF-8"` produced no visible change either.

The application works otherwise just fine at every level.
I figured it might be a problem of setting the proper encoding when opening and copying the template and tried to change this line

`Workbook template = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(Constants.TEMPLATE_PATH);`

to

`Workbook template = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(Constants.TEMPLATE_PATH, XLSSettings);`

but it produces an ArrayOutOfBoundException in `java.lang.System.arraycopy` propagating from this line `userDocument.write();` via

```
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
        jxl.biff.StringHelper.getBytes(StringHelper.java:127)
        jxl.write.biff.WriteAccessRecord.<init>(WriteAccessRecord.java:59)
        jxl.write.biff.WritableWorkbookImpl.write(WritableWorkbookImpl.java:726)
        com.mypackage.MyClass.createFile(MyClass.java:337)
```

Anyone ever encountered the problem and know how to fix it ?

Answer (score 7):

I was facing this problem too. The solution, for me, was very easy. I just had to put my WorkbookSettings just in the TEMPLATE wb and not in the new file.

```
//Load template workbook with settings
WorkbookSettings ws = new WorkbookSettings();
ws.setEncoding("Cp1252");

Workbook templateWorkbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(this.context.getAssets().open("template.xls"), ws);

//Create new workbook from templateWorkbook without settings
this.workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(this.location), templateWorkbook);
```

Found at: [Android and JXL : ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException when create WritableWorkbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455540/android-and-jxl-arrayindexoutofboundexception-when-create-writableworkbook)

Regards